# Instagram Real-time API can't see my server

Tags: python, flask, instagram-api

I'm testing the Instagram Real-time API with Python and Flask and I get everytime this response from the Instagram server:

```
{  
   "meta":{  
      "error_type":"APISubscriptionError",
      "code":400,
      "error_message":"Unable to reach callback URL \"http:\/\/my_callback_url:8543\/instagram\"."
   }
}
```

The request:

```
curl -F 'client_id=my_client_id...' \
     -F 'client_secret=my_client_secret...' \
     -F 'object=tag' \
     -F 'aspect=media' \
     -F 'object_id=fox' \
     -F 'callback_url=http://my_callback_url:8543/instagram' \
     https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```

And this is the code of the Flask server:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

from instagram import subscriptions

app = Flask(__name__)

CLIENT_ID = "my_client_id..."
CLIENT_SECRET = "my_client_secret..."


def process_tag_update(update):
    print 'Received a push: ', update

reactor = subscriptions.SubscriptionsReactor()
reactor.register_callback(subscriptions.SubscriptionType.TAG, process_tag_update)


@app.route('/instagram', methods=['GET'])
def handshake():
    # GET method is used when validating the endpoint as per the Pubsubhubub protocol
    mode = request.values.get('hub.mode')
    challenge = request.values.get('hub.challenge')
    verify_token = request.values.get('hub.verify_token')
    if challenge:
        return challenge
    return 'It is not a valid challenge'

@app.route('/instagram', methods=['POST'])
def callback():
    # POST event is used to for the events notifications
    x_hub_signature = request.headers.get('X-Hub-Signature')
    raw_response = request.data
    try:
        reactor.process(CLIENT_SECRET, raw_response, x_hub_signature)
    except subscriptions.SubscriptionVerifyError:
        print 'Signature mismatch'
    return 'done'

def server():
    """ Main server, will allow us to make it wsgi'able """
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8543, debug=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server()
```

The machine have a public IP and the port is open for everyone. I can reach the url from others networks.

Why can't Instagram reach my url? Is there a black list or something like that?

---

**Update 1**

I have tested the same code with some frameworks and WSGI servers (Django, Flask, Node.js, Gunicorn, Apache) and different responses in the GET/POST endpoint and I always get the same 400 error message.

Also I have checked the packages received in my network interface with Wireshark and I get the expected results with calls from any network. But I don't get any package when I do the subscription request.

So... Is this a bug? Could be my IP in any blacklist for some reason?

Comment: Having the same problem, haven't found any solution though. Sometimes (rarely) it works. Most of the time I get the same error as you

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same. It worked when I accidentally restarted the router, getting a different IP. It seems that it could be an IP issue indeed and the `Unable to reach callback URL...` is not really helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, there are plenty of AWS servers answering to that API and some are not working. Ping api.instagram.com and you'll see you get multiple and different IP for that domain name. There is a DNS round robin and you are not reaching the same server every time.

I've found one server (IP : 52.6.133.72) which seems to be working for subscription and have configured my server to use that one (by editing the /etc/hosts file). Not a reliable solution ... but it's working.